# Django Forms multiple foreignkey

Tags: django, django-forms

I have four models, three of which have ‘independent’ fields but the fourth models has ForeignKey links to the other three.

```
class PreCheck(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    time_in     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_insured = models.BooleanField()

class MainCheck(models.Model):
    height = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()

class PostCheck(models.Model):
    sickness = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    medication = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
    patient =   models.ForeignKey(User)
    next_check_date = models.DateTimeField()
    payment_amount  = models.IntegerField()

    initial_check = models.ForeignKey(PreCheck)
    main_check = models.ForeignKey(MainCheck)
    post_check = models.ForeignKey(PostCheck)
```

Assume a patient goes in a room, a precheck is done and saved, then other checks are done and finally a final record is set.

**Ideally, I would like to fill in forms for the different models at different times possibly in different pages/tabs.**

The admin has popups for the MedicalRecord model but in the frontend its hard to write javascript for that.
Another option would be to fill in the modelforms separately and do a **str** return function then select that from dropdowns in the MedicalRecord form( which I’m trying to avoid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add blank=True, null=True for each ForeignKey fields.

```
initial_check = models.ForeignKey(PreCheck, blank=True, null=True)
main_check = models.ForeignKey(MainCheck, blank=True, null=True)
post_check = models.ForeignKey(PostCheck, blank=True, null=True)
```

at the initial check, you can create MedicalRecord with help of MedicalRecord model-form, this time main_check and post_check record can be left [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#blank).
after main check, you can update MedicalRecord with main_check details, this time left blank post_check record, and keep updating your MedicalRecord on different pages/tabs with available details.